# How can Ubuntu's theme be changed?

Tags: themes

Ubuntu is orange. But I want it to be green. Can I customise it so that all folders and tool bars will be green?

Comment: For example, you can use Unity Tweak Tool (if you use Unity) or the same utility with only Gnome (if you use Gnome)

Answer (score 2):

Do you want to keep the default theme and just change the accent colours or do you want to install a new theme completely? Both are a viable option but the method depends on which version of ubuntu you have installed. Here are the procedures for (almost) all versions of ubuntu here:

This is a guide on how to theme Ubuntu prior to 17.10: [How To Install Themes In Ubuntu 14.04 and 16.04 | itsfoss.com](https://itsfoss.com/how-to-install-themes-in-ubuntu-13-10/)

For ubuntu 17.10 onwards: [How to Install Themes in Ubuntu 18.04 and 17.10 | itsfoss.com](https://itsfoss.com/install-themes-ubuntu/)

Now that you know how to theme ubuntu to turn it green I'd suggest "Ambience and radiance colors" (for ubuntu 16.04 and below). To install it open a terminal and type these commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ravefinity-project/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ambiance-colors radiance-colors
```

From ubuntu 17.10 onwards this option isn't viable. I'd suggest the adapta theme with papirus-adapta icons. to install the adapta theme type in a terminal these commands:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:tista/adapta
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install adapta-gtk-theme
```

To install the icons type:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:papirus/papirus
sudo apt update && sudo apt install papirus-icon-theme
```

This will also install other variants of the papirus icons.